# Heroku Dyno Free Hours Reset Monthly?

Tags: heroku

I have still 981hours for today's month what if I will not consume this hours. In the following month does this 981 hours will reset to 1000 hours ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you don't use some hours at the end of the month, your quota goes back to the base value.
You cannot keep unused dyno hours month over month.